# AWS Cloudfront signed cookies not working with alternate domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution with an S3 Bucket as origin.
I also have a alternate domain for the cloudfront distribution.
`CF-URL: dxxx.cloudfront.net`
`ALTR-URL: cdn.mydomain.com`

Now, I want to use signed cookies to give access to all the files in a specific folder in the S3 bucket. So I made a function which generates the 3 required cookies:

- CloudFront-Policy
- CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id
- CloudFront-Signature

I've done all the key group and public/private key stuff. Here is the function which generates the cookies:

```
function cookie(req, res) {
    const privateKeyPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "private_key.pem")
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, "utf8")
    const keyPairId = process.env.CLOUDFRONT_KEY_PAIR_ID
    expires = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000)

    const policy = {
        Statement: [
            {
                Resource: `https://cdn.mydomain.com/videos/*`,
                Condition: {
                    DateLessThan: {
                        "AWS:EpochTime": expires,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    }

    policyString = JSON.stringify(policy)
    const policyBase64 = Buffer.from(policyString).toString("base64")
    res.cookie("CloudFront-Policy", policyBase64, {
        domain: ".mydomain.com",
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
    })

    res.cookie("CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id", keyPairId, {
        domain: ".mydomain.com",
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
    })

    const policyStatementNoSpace = policyString.replace(/\s/g, "")
    const sign = crypto.createSign("SHA1")
    sign.update(policyStatementNoSpace)
    const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, "base64")
    const base64EncodedString = Buffer.from(signature, "base64").toString(
        "base64"
    )
    const urlSafeString = base64EncodedString
        .replace(/\+/g, "-")
        .replace(/\//g, "~")
        .replace(/=/g, "_")
    res.cookie("CloudFront-Signature", urlSafeString, {
        domain: ".mydomain.com",
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
    })
    
    res.end()
}
```

Now, here is the main part I don't understand. In the function at line 10:

```
Resource: `https://cdn.streamts.tech/videos/*`
```

Let's call the cookies generated by using the Resource url: `https://dxxx.cloudfront.net/videos/*` as `CF_Cookies`
and the ones generated using the url:
`https://cdn.streamts.tech/videos/*` as `ALTR_Cookies`.

And assume I'm trying to access a file: `https://dxxx.cloudfront.net/videos/cat.mp4` or `https://cdn.streamts.tech/videos/cat.mp4`

(Tested in Postman)
When I try to access the video by passing the CF_Cookies and using the `dxxx.cloudfront.net` url, it works. As expected, I am only allowed to view data in the video/ folder and no other data.
But, If I try passing the ALTR_Cookies and using the `cdn.mydomain.net` url, I get access denied error.
I've tried all 4 combinations of url and cookies but one of them works which is using the CF_Cookies and `dxxx.cloudfront.net` url.

Note that the alternate domain does work when I set the `Restrict viewer access` to `No` in cloudfront, I can access the videos using `cdn.mydomain.com`. It is only that the signed cookies don't work with the alternate domain.